# Селекторы в jquery

Tags: jquery

Допустим есть вот такая вёрстка

```
<div class="1">
 <!-- some content-->
</div>

<div class="1">
 <!-- other content-->
</div>
```

мне нужно чтоб при наведении на конкретный div класса 1 происходило действие именно с тем div'ом на который навёл

Comment: @timmi, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [JQuery селекторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/99944/jquery-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.class_name').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color','#CCC');
});

$('.class_name').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color','#CCC');
});

$('.class_name').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color','#CCC');
});
```

Comment: немного не так сформулировал. извиняюсь. что действия выполняли с именно тем div'ом на который навёл

Comment: Подправил ответ. Используйте **$(this)** и какой-то метод

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).text('true');
});
```