# Обращение к вложенному элементу с помощью JQuery селекторов

Tags: jquery, css

Есть верстка:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .hidden{
   display:none;
   }
</style>

<div class="1">
<div class="hidden"></div>
</div>

<div class="1">
<div class="hidden"></div>
</div>
```

Нужно, чтобы при наведении на **конкретный** div класса 1, появлялся опять же конкретный (который внутри этого div'а) div класса hidden

Когда пишешь вот так:

```
$(".1").mouseover(function(){
    $(".hidden").css("display","block");
});
```

срабатывают все одновременно. Как сделать, чтобы было правильно? И можно ли вообще с помощью jquery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$(".1").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).children(".hidden").css("display","block");
});
```

Учите матчасть! И хватит юзать JS там, где можно обойтись CSS!

```
.1:hover .hidden { display:block }
```

Comment: там за место .css будет fadeIn или slideup потому брал js. спасибо за ответ

Comment: Если на старые бровзеры плевать, трушней будет заюзать `css3 animation`

Comment: Рановато на CSS3 перепрыгивать. Кроме осла и у Оперы проблемы, и даже в Хроме баги замечал. Чуток еще подождать надо.